# Can Nginx return a 503 error code on "deny all"?

Tags: nginx

I want to put my site into a "maintenance mode", so that only my IP address can access it. This is easy to do with something like this:

```
location /
{
   allow 1.1.1.1;
   deny all;
}
```

...but that returns a 403 (Forbidden) message instead of a 503 (Service Unavailable) error code. Is there any way to return a 503 via "deny all" instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add this line in that location

```
error_page 403 =503 /error_503.html;
```

The `/error_503.html` is a normal html page that will be served with the 503 error code

Comment: I added that below "deny all", but now by browser dumps to "/=503" and reports a redirect loop.

Comment: ok i guess you need to supply the error page too, ill edit my answer

Comment: That works! I know we aren't supposed to use these comments to say "thanks", but this really helped me solve a big problem I was dealing with and I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution where you don't have to create a html file is to do like this

```
location @error503 {
   default_type text/html;
   return 405 "<body><h1>503 Service unavailable</h1></body>";
}


location /
{
   error_page 403 @error503;
   allow 1.1.1.1;
   deny all;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).